# openssl claims to use /private/etc/ssl, but appears not to, What The Heck?

Tags: high-sierra, openssl

In the course of trying to help a friend with a problem with pip and ssl sites ([GitHub issue here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7663)), I've become confused about how the High Sierra /usr/bin/openssl finds its certificates.  My "keg-only" openssl does not have any trouble with the site.

Here's the test case that I've been playing with:

```
(alice)[14:22:06]~>>/usr/bin/openssl s_client -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443 | head 2>&1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign CloudSSL CA - SHA256 - G3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
CONNECTED(00000005)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Francisco/O=Fastly, Inc/CN=r.ssl.fastly.net
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign CloudSSL CA - SHA256 - G3
 1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign CloudSSL CA - SHA256 - G3
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
^C
```

I've been scratching my head because an appropriate key resides in the Keychain utility (Determined by downloading the Mozilla cert bundle from the Curl site, finding the one cert that rescues the test case when provided via `-CAfile`, and comparing its fingerprint to certs in the Keychain app.  See [the pip issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7663) for gory details).

The value of `OPENSSLDIR` in the `openssl version -a` output suggests that `/usr/bin/openssl` should be using `/private/etc/ssl`:

```
(alice)[14:05:27]~>>/usr/bin/openssl version -a
LibreSSL 2.2.7
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"
```

And, in fact, pointing at that directory with the `-CApath` command line option rescues the test case:

```
(alice)[14:26:32]~>>/usr/bin/openssl s_client -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443 -CApath /private/etc/ssl | head 2>&1 < /dev/null
depth=2 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign CloudSSL CA - SHA256 - G3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "Fastly, Inc", CN = r.ssl.fastly.net
verify return:1
^C
(alice)[15:21:22]~>>
```

What's going on?  Do the `CApath/CAfile` commands enable behavior that doesn't otherwise occur?

I'd love to understand what's going on.

Comment: "pointing at that directory with the `-CApath` command line option rescues the test case: [...]" — the terminal output you've provided here is identical to the first case (no `-CApath`) and doesn't show success; can you correct this? I assume you're correctly seeing `verify return:1` for the entire chain (root cert at `depth=2` as I see it) in this second case?

Comment: To actually answer your question about the cert location, though, it is indeed `/etc/ssl/` as you suspect (note that `/etc` is symlinked to `/private/etc`). The default certs all reside there in `cert.pem`, and additional certs can be stored in `/etc/ssl/certs/`. Perhaps check that your `cert.pem` is intact and up to date? For me, running LibreSSL 2.8.3 on macOS Catalina 10.15.2 (19C57), the MD5 hash of `cert.pem` is `6cecca9c114e4386b98e1d24a028dd95`.

Comment: For me, in `cert.pem`, the GlobalSign root cert can be found starting on line 3018. The cert itself can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/KZQANumd

Comment: For me, I have a copy of the "rescuing cert" starting a line 176, its fingerprint (from the file itself) is:   233 SHA1 Fingerprint=B1:BC:96:8B:D4:F4:9D:62:2A:A8:9A:81:F2:15:01:52:A4:1D:82:9C

Comment: I've fixed my cut-and-paste issue, sorry and thanks.  @jivanpal you are correct that I see `verify return: ``

Comment: Can you provide the entire output of the `openssl` command up to `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` like you did in the first case, without piping it to `head` and redirecting `stderr` and `stdout` to `/dev/null`? I don't see any "rescue" occurring, nor do I know what you mean when you say that. Additionally, your `cert.pem` *must* differ from mine, then. Line 1 of mine reads `# $OpenBSD: cert.pem,v 1.17 2018/09/12 22:17:08 sthen Exp $` — what about yours?

Comment: Also, `B1:BC:96:8B:D4:F4:9D:62:2A:A8:9A:81:F2:15:01:52:A4:1D:82:9C` is the SHA1 fingerprint of the root cert in question — see the Pastebin link I provided earlier; it is the same.

Comment: Here's a gist of the failing and "rescued" test cases (rescued is a biology term for adding something that then allows a test to succeed):  https://gist.github.com/hartzell/14b168f95b8dc2a66a97bfce42a9d895

Comment: My /private/etc/certs.pem starts off with: 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Serial Number: 421 (0x1a5)
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=GTE Corporation, OU=GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc., CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 13 00:29:00 1998 GMT
            Not After : Aug 13 23:59:00 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=GTE Corporation, OU=GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc., CN=GTE CyberTrust Global Root

Comment: I've added my /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem to the gist at: https://gist.github.com/hartzell/14b168f95b8dc2a66a97bfce42a9d895

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103825/discussion-between-jivan-pal-and-hartzell).

Comment: @JivanPal -- re your comment about our fingerprints matching.  That's the essence of my question: why do I get a failure when I don't specify any CApath/CAfile options, but get successful verification when I explicitly point at the directory that's supposed to be the default?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103825/discussion-between-jivan-pal-and-hartzell).

Comment: There is no need to add the edit history in the post. Anybody interest in it can see all [revisions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/380806/revisions) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is the result of a [known bug in OpenSSL](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142159/how-to-get-openssl-to-use-a-cert-without-specifying-it-via-cafile) that was reported in February 2013 and [tracked here](https://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3697) (log in using username `guest` and password `guest`). At the time, the latest public release of OpenSSL was OpenSSL 1.0.2. The issue was marked resolved in October 2016, and the bug no longer exists in releases after this date, the earliest of which is OpenSSL 1.1.1. Some users have reported that the bug was also not present in "version 1.1", to which they may be referring to OpenSSL 1.1.0 or forks of it — I have not confirmed whether the bug exists in OpenSSL 1.1.0.

The `openssl` binary included with macOS is LibreSSL, which is a fork of OpenSSL that originated from OpenSSL 1.0.1g. Since the bug existed in that version of OpenSSL, it persisted in LibreSSL until it was noticed and fixed by their developers, which was somewhere between the version you're using (LibreSSL 2.2.7) and the version I'm using (LibreSSL 2.8.3, which is packaged with macOS Catalina).